# Why does the .screenrc key binding ^@a map to ctrl+space?

Tags: gnu-screen

In my .screenrc I have the following stanza:

```
# Change command key to ctrl+space
escape ^@a
```

I found this magic incantation in a forum I can no longer find; it allows me to hit ctrl+space to invoke screen commands, so `ctrl+space c` (or `ctrl+space ctrl+c`) will create a new window, and `ctrl+space space` (or `ctrl+space ctrl+space`) will switch to the last window, etc.

This is very useful in avoiding the problem of precluding the `ctrl+a` beginning-of-line terminal functionality, is easy to type and doesn't conflict with any standard keybindings.

Can anyone explain why and how this works? I have searched through https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html for any reference to the character `@` and found nothing relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a lot of terminal programs (but not every one), control-SPACE sends the ASCII 00 character (NUL).

You can see this, eg with `od -cx` and entering control-SPACE, RETURN, control_D.  You'll see output similar to:

```
% od -cx
^@
0000000  \0  \n
           0a00
0000002
```

Control-@ is also the NUL character (@ is ASCII 64, so control-@ is ASCII 00).

So mapping control-@ inside screen has the effect of mapping control-SPACE... because of how the terminal handles control-SPACE.

Comment: Wow. And to corroborate further, ctrl+shift+2 (ctrl+@) works for me too :-)